# Determine if there is any VNC display desktop active and its number

Tags: shell-script, desktop, display

When **SSH loging** into my Linux computer, how could I know if there is any X-Windows desktop **display** session (i.e: :1 started by VNCServer) active and what is its number?

**Reason**:
I sometimes remotely start iMacros FireFox scripts that need GUI, so if there is no desktop started, I must power on it by issuing:

```
vncserver -name Computer
```

If it is started, after knowing its number (i.e: `:1.0`) I do:

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
firefox imacros://run/?m=MyMacro.iim
```

I use to try:

```
$ sudo ps -e | grep "vnc" -i
 1685 ?        06:28:53 Xtightvnc
```

But that does not yield me the number (i.e: `:1.0`).

Further data upon requestion (there is a running VNC on :1):

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp|grep -i vnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1685/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1685/Xtightvnc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11847    1685/Xtightvnc      /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

Answer (score 2):

By default vnc uses port 5901 for display 1 and so on up. So you can use netstat to list all listening processes and calculate the display from those:

```
export DISPLAY="$(netstat -ln |
 awk '$4~/:59[0-9][0-9]$/{
  v=$4; sub(/.*:/,"",v);
  print ":" v-5900; exit}')"
```

This assumes your netstat outputs something like `0.0.0.0:5901` in field 4. The awk removes everything up to the ":" and subtracts 5900 from it. The DISPLAY is set in the environment for the following firefox. If you want to combine this with the launch of vncserver, put it in a function, say getdisplay, and use it as follows:

```
getdisplay(){
  ... as above
}
getdisplay
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]
then    vncserver -name Computer
        getdisplay
fi
firefox ...
```

Comment: Showing no results on Kali Linux with VNCServer on display :1 .

Comment: Stil not working. Edited original post with your request.

Comment: Well, I don't remember your change, but I am copy pasting your `eval` code, and there is no output on screen.

Comment: There will be no output. It should set the DISPLAY variable in the environment. So add `echo $DISPLAY` to see if it set it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I got it now. Sorry, I did not correctly look at your code. Indeed, the variable is filled with the correct `:1` value. And your getdisplay function will be useful too for me, thanks you. But I was rather using `:1.0` as $DISPLAY value. I assume it is the same thing (I am not very pro at X-Windows).

Comment: Your use of `eval` here is vulnerable to remote code execution. I don't understand why you're using it, anyway, you could just as well print the display number and do `export DISPLAY="$(...)"`.

Comment: @ChrisDown I agree eval is to be avoided normally. In this case I control what awk can produce, so there is no problem.

Comment: @meuh You're fighting a losing battle if you're trying to sanitise command output. There's literally no reason to use `eval` here.